# AsyncImage get picture from program source?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

from this code

```
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "ImageCache.h"
#import "ImageCacheObject.h"

static ImageCache *imageCache = nil;

@implementation AsyncImageView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [connection cancel];
    [connection release];
    [data release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url {
    if (connection != nil) {
        [connection cancel];
        [connection release];
        connection = nil;
    }
    if (data != nil) {
        [data release];
        data = nil;
    }

    if (imageCache == nil) 
        imageCache = [[ImageCache alloc] initWithMaxSize:2*1024*1024]; 

    [urlString release];
    urlString = [[url absoluteString] copy];
    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache imageForKey:urlString];
    if (cachedImage != nil) 
    {   NSLog(@"get in");
        if ([[self subviews] count] > 0) 
        {
            [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
        }
        UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cachedImage] autorelease];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.autoresizingMask = 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.frame = self.bounds;
        [imageView setNeedsLayout]; 
        [self setNeedsLayout];
        return;
    }

#define SPINNY_TAG 5555   

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinny = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinny.tag = SPINNY_TAG;
    spinny.center = self.center;
    [spinny startAnimating];
    [self addSubview:spinny];
    [spinny release];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                         timeoutInterval:60.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {
    if (data==nil) {
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];
    }
    [data appendData:incrementalData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection {
    [connection release];
    connection = nil;

    UIView *spinny = [self viewWithTag:SPINNY_TAG];
    [spinny removeFromSuperview];

    if ([[self subviews] count] > 0) {
        [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    [imageCache insertImage:image withSize:[data length] forKey:urlString];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] 
                               initWithImage:image] autorelease];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.frame = self.bounds;
    [imageView setNeedsLayout]; // is this necessary if superview gets setNeedsLayout?
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [data release];
    data = nil;
}

@end
```

If I wanna get picture from app source if url is empty , what code should I add ??

and here is more code from xyz.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.newsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else{
        AsyncImageView *oldImage = (AsyncImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
        [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
    }
    int index = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    //Get Picture
    CGRect frame;
    frame.size.width=50; frame.size.height=50;
    frame.origin.x=10; frame.origin.y=0;
    AsyncImageView* asyncImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    asyncImage.tag = 999;

    NSString *string = [jsonPic objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *url=[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    if([string isEqualToString:@""]){
     NSLog(@"Not found");
```

at here I don't know How can I get picture from source

```
        AsyncImageView * NoImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
        NoImage.tag = 999;
        NoImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bl-noImg.gif"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:NoImage];
    }
    else
    {   NSLog(@"image  URL %@",imageURL);
       [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:imageURL];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];
```

I can get picture from asyncImage

Please , Help me or guide me to do that. thank you 
.
.
.
.
Now It's all done and here is my result code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.newsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else{
        AsyncImageView *oldImage = (AsyncImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
        [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
    }
    int index = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    //Get Picture
    CGRect frame;
    frame.size.width=50; frame.size.height=50;
    frame.origin.x=10; frame.origin.y=0;
    AsyncImageView* asyncImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    asyncImage.tag = 999;

    NSString *string = [jsonPic objectAtIndex:index];
     if([string isEqualToString:@""]){
     //NSLog(@"Not found");
        UIImageView * NoImg = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
        NoImg.tag = 999;
        [NoImg setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bg-noImg" ofType:@"gif"]]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:NoImg];
    }
    else
    {   //NSLog(@"image  URL %@",imageURL);
        NSString *url=[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:imageURL];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];
    }
```

thank you everyone : )

Comment: then you should not create request and call connection(check for url). Do you still need some picture to display?(then you can use some default image,(also in the case when url returns nothing... no image then you should use some default pictures)

Comment: so I should create if(check URL) in xyz.m , right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are checking for empty url then you should check it before calling to loadImageFromURL and even before creating NSURL object. If it is not empty then you should create NSURL object and call loadImageFromURL method.

somewhere in your code... from where you are calling loadImageFromURL:

```
    if(urlString !=nil || [urlString length]>0)
    {
     create NSURL object
     now again check NSURL object whether its nil or not
     we are checking it because if the urlString has incorrect url pattern then no
 NSURLObject would be created, so if there is no NSURLObject then we should not call
 your method.
     if(NSURLObject !=nil)
     {
        call loadImageFromURL method and so on
     }
     else
     {
       //load some default image. which will convey no URL Found
     }

    }
    else
     {
       //load some default image. which will convey no URL Found
     }
```

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure where you need help? Is there some connection issues? Image is not getting loaded? or something else? please mention it

Comment: Oh All my problem are fix. First I have problem that I don't know how can I get picture from my app source. Thank you very much :)